# Question regarding Ehrenfest paradox in Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity

Recently, I read a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_paradox) regarding the paradox that made this statement about the reference frame:

> The reference frame is fixed to the stationary center of the disk. Then the magnitude of the relative velocity of any point in the circumference of the disc....

How is it possible that the center of a rotating disc is fixed and stationary. I believe that any observer ( with any finite width) on the "center" of this disc will rotate with the same angular velocity as an observer on the circumference. Have I misunderstood?

Edit: A number of comments and answers have stated the center of a rotating solid disk is stationary. This is because the center point has no width so no tangential velocity so no rotation.

I don't agree.

The radian is a pure constant: no units.
Angular velocity is in $$\frac{rads}{sec}$$ or $$\frac{1}{sec}$$ The point doesn't need width to have an angular velocity because angular velocity isn't $\frac{meters}{sec}$

For a Cartesian coordinate sysyem moving at a constant velocity v, every point in that frame is moving ay v and special relativity applies.

For a circular coordinate system moving at a constant angular velocity $\omega$, every point in that frame is moving at $\omega$ including the center otherwise special relativity can't be used.

This problem can't be solved using SR unless the center of the rotating disc rotates at constant $\omega$ as well.

Comment: The centre is a point with zero width not finite width. That is why it is stationary.

Comment: @JohnRennie Thanks, John. It seems to me that this way of thinking about center point makes it impossible for an observer to make a measurement since the observer is forced to be at zero width. Why not make the non-rotating reference frame outside the circumference of the circle. This seems far more realistic in terms of measurement.

Comment: I think you are taking this too literally. An observer is a hypothetical construct and need not be physically realistic.

Comment: Hi @JohnRennie. I've edited my question to include your comment about a zero width point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you model an observer by a worldline. You then associate at every event a orthogonal basis (with respect to the Minkowski metric) such that the time-like 4-vector is tangent to the worldline. They represent the frame of the observer at every time.

The frame is Fermi-Walker transported along the worldline iff the observer is not rotating and it’s the analogue of translational motion.

In your case, the worldline is straight , but the frame rotates. The crux of Ehrenfest’s paradox is that you cannot consistently extend this infinitesimal frame to a neighborhood of the worldline.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

We could put the central observer on a non rotating platform just above (or just below) the rotating cylinder. It is obvious from the the Wikipedia article that the central observer is not supposed to be rotating, because they say this observer sees the cylinder rotate with angular velocity $\omega$ while a rotating observer would not.

> Why not make the non-rotating reference frame outside the
> circumference of the circle. This seems far more realistic in terms of
> measurement.

You are correct that the point of view of inertial observers outside the cylinder is equally valid and more intuitive. Since tangential velocity $v = \omega r$ they would see a small segment of the rim of the cylinder pass them a velocity of v with a length contraction factor of $$\sqrt{1-(\omega r)^2/c^2} = \sqrt{1-v^2/c^2} \ .$$

Conventionally the centre point is chosen as a reference point because it can technically be said to be non rotating if it has a zero width and is just a matter of convenience. The maths works out the same.

=====================================================

Just for fun, here are some bizarre but true facts about measurements in a rotating reference frame:

Lets say an inertial observer lays N calibrated rulers (each with rest length L) all the way around the outside of the rotating cylinder and the tangential velocity of the cylinder is $v_T = \sqrt{3/4}$ c clockwise. Another observer (with a bag full of calibrated rulers) enters the rotating cylinder at the centre and slowly walks out to the perimeter and places the rulers all the way around the rim of the cylinder. He finds he has to place 2N rulers to complete the circle. He sends a light signal clockwise around the rim and finds it takes

$(N L/c)(\sqrt{c+v}/\sqrt{c-v} \approx 3.73205 N L/c $ seconds

to return. He sends another signal anticlockwise and it takes

$(N L/c)(\sqrt{c-v}/\sqrt{c+v} \approx 0.267949 N L/c $ seconds.

*He discovers the speed of light is direction dependent in a rotating reference frame*! To compromise, he takes the average of the clockwise and anticlockwise time measurements and calculates the average radar measurement of the cylinder rim circumference to be

$N L / \sqrt{1-v^2/c^2} = 2 N L $ seconds

in agreement with his local ruler measurement.

He picks a marker on the outside and times how long it takes to go from the front of one his rulers to the back and gets a tangential velocity of objects outside the cylinder as moving at v. He now times how long it takes the external marker to pass him and return. Due to time dilation of his clock the result he calculates that the perimeter of inertial rulers outside the cylinders measures:

$1/2 N L $ light seconds.

By his measurements the outside inertial circumference is $1/4$ of his local ruler measurements of the rim, or smaller by a factor of $\gamma^2$.

He measures the radius (R) to be the same as that measured by the inertial observers when he uses rulers, but if he times how long a signal to go to the centre and return, he measures the radar radius to be $R/2$ light seconds. No matter how he measures the radius and the circumference in his own reference frame he cannot get the expected $ 2 \pi R$ result and discovers that his spacetime in the rotating reference frame is definitely not Euclidean.

He also discovers:

1. There is no way to get all his clocks to synchronise. He could adjust the clocks artificially all the way around, to come up with some sort of coordinate system, but when he does that he finds the length of rulers depends on whether they are measured left to right or right to left and the speed of light is directional even locally.

$Any projectiles or loose objects do not travel in a straight line.

Comment: I've updated my question to include your comments about whether the center rotates in a rotating rigid disk. Thanks.